# How do I transform a class/window from a "normal" window to a Toplevel() window in Tkinter?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

I'm new to programming in Tkinter and I'm trying to make the window/class "GraphPage_cpu" a Toplevel() window within this structure. How do I go about make it so that pressing the button "CPU Usage" on the "StartPage" and make it open a new window containing the graph page?

**Also I have to give a huge credit to the user, "j_4321". He really helped me a lot with figuring out how to plot cpu measures!**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import Toplevel
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo, showwarning, askquestion
from tkinter import OptionMenu
from tkinter import StringVar

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from psutil import cpu_percent
from psutil import virtual_memory
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sklearn.cluster as cluster
import scipy.spatial.distance as sdist
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sn

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

RANDOM_STATE = 42 #used to help randomly select the data points
low_memory=False
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")

f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)


class Analyticsapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconimage_kmeans.ico") #Icon for program
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Advanched analytics")
        
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        self.frames = {} 
        
        for F in (StartPage, GraphPage_cpu):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text=
                         "Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="CPU Usage", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(GraphPage_cpu))
        button3.pack(fill='x')

class GraphPage_cpu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, nb_points=360):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="CPU Usage", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side='top')

        # matplotlib figure
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # format the x-axis to show the time
        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
        # initial x and y data
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=-nb_points)
        self.x_data = [dateTimeObj + timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(nb_points)]
        self.y_data = [0 for i in range(nb_points)]
        # create the plot
        self.plot = self.ax.plot(self.x_data, self.y_data, label='CPU')[0]
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack(side='bottom')
        
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.animate_cpu()

    def animate_cpu(self):
        # append new data point to the x and y data
        self.x_data.append(datetime.now())
        self.y_data.append(cpu_percent())
        # remove oldest data point
        self.x_data = self.x_data[1:]
        self.y_data = self.y_data[1:]
        #  update plot data
        self.plot.set_xdata(self.x_data)
        self.plot.set_ydata(self.y_data)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])
        self.canvas.draw_idle()  # redraw plot
        self.after(1000, self.animate_cpu)  # repeat after 1s
        
app = Analyticsapp()
app.geometry('500x400')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: "He really helped me ..." : thanks for the credit, but just so you know, I'm a woman.  I think it's good practice to use gender-neutral pronouns when in doubt, or avoid using pronouns: e.g.  "... j_4321, who really helped me ...".

Comment: Sorry for that. I think it is more a result of english not being my first language. -But I will be mindful of this in the future. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Don't worry, I did not take it badly, but I thought it was better to let you know because sometimes it can hurt people's feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `GraphPage_cpu` inherit from `Toplevel` instead of `Frame`:

```
class GraphPage_cpu(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller, nb_points=360):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        ...
```

Then, you need to change `button1` command since the graph is no longer hiding the Start Page, maybe use `self.withdraw` to hide the graph when clicking on the button. In this case, you no longer need the `controller` argument in `__init__`.

Now, you need to modify `Analyticsapp.__init__`: `GraphPage_cpu` is now a Toplevel, not a Frame, so you have to remove it from the for loop that creates all your pages. You can create it separately, like:

```
 self.graph_cpu = GraphPage_cpu(self, nb_points=360)
 self.graph_cpu.withdraw()  # hide the toplevel
```

And add a class method to show the toplevel:

```
def show_graph_cpu(self):
    self.graph_cpu.deiconify()
```

Finally you need to modify `button3` in Start Page to show the graph:

```
button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="CPU Usage", 
                     command=controller.show_graph_cpu)
```

Here is the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from psutil import cpu_percent
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


RANDOM_STATE = 42 #used to help randomly select the data points
low_memory = False
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
style.use("ggplot")


class Analyticsapp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, default="iconimage_kmeans.ico") #Icon for program
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Advanched analytics")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage,):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.graph_cpu = GraphPage_cpu(self, nb_points=360)
        self.graph_cpu.withdraw()  # hide window

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    def show_graph(self):
        self.graph_cpu.deiconify()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Advanched analytics", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="CPU Usage",
                             command=controller.show_graph)
        button3.pack(fill='x')

class GraphPage_cpu(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, nb_points=360):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.withdraw)  # make the close button in the titlebar withdraw the toplevel instead of destroying it
        label = tk.Label(self, text="CPU Usage", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10, side='top')

        # matplotlib figure
        self.figure = Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        # format the x-axis to show the time
        myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S")
        self.ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
        # initial x and y data
        dateTimeObj = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=-nb_points)
        self.x_data = [dateTimeObj + timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(nb_points)]
        self.y_data = [0 for i in range(nb_points)]
        # create the plot
        self.plot = self.ax.plot(self.x_data, self.y_data, label='CPU')[0]
        self.ax.set_ylim(0, 100)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Hide", command=self.withdraw)
        button1.pack(side='bottom')

        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.animate_cpu()

    def animate_cpu(self):
        # append new data point to the x and y data
        self.x_data.append(datetime.now())
        self.y_data.append(cpu_percent())
        # remove oldest data point
        self.x_data = self.x_data[1:]
        self.y_data = self.y_data[1:]
        #  update plot data
        self.plot.set_xdata(self.x_data)
        self.plot.set_ydata(self.y_data)
        self.ax.set_xlim(self.x_data[0], self.x_data[-1])
        self.canvas.draw_idle()  # redraw plot
        self.after(1000, self.animate_cpu)  # repeat after 1s

app = Analyticsapp()
app.geometry('500x400')
app.mainloop()
```

Also, in `GraphPage_cpu.__init__`, I have added

```
self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.withdraw)
```

that makes the close button in the titlebar withdraw the toplevel instead of destroying it.

Comment: Thank you very much! This saved the day. WM_DELETE_WINDOW is the icing on the cake!